# what are the react native libraries that helps you to display some statistics

Tags: reactjs, react-native, statistics, analytics

Is there a library for React Native that will help us to see the numbers of how many people for example swiped down until most bottom of FlatList in Newsfeed module or how many times login button is pressed by x users or how many minutes or seconds did people stay in their profile tab ? 
Is there any implementation or library that can help us to display these kind of statistical results for React Native apps ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firebase Analytics. Examine [this link](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.1.x/analytics/reference/analytics).

Basically, after install and import that, create an Analytics object:

```
let Analytics = firebase.analytics();
```

Now, you can use any event whatever you want. Just write a code on your onPress method like this:

```
Analytics.logEvent('EventName','Parameters'}
```